# Why null value also satisfies the if condition of simple while True command and break condition?

Tags: python, pydroid

[My python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD1LS.jpg)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJi8q.jpg)

I have used pydroid3 in my mobile and I couldn't get why null values also satisfies the if condition.

I Just pressed the enter button.

Comment: What if condition?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

`input` function returns a string, so if you're not entering anything, it does not return a null value, it returns an empty string `''`. You can check this via:

```
'' == input()
```

And you'll see that an empty string satisfies your condition via:

```
'' in 'Yy'
```

Which evaluates to `True`